# SObject tree/SObject collections composite api limits

Tags: rest-api

With regards to standard composite API (containing up to 25 subrequests) we have information re: API consumption here; https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite.htm

Which reads:

> The entire request counts as a single call toward your API limits.

However, I can't find anything similar for the SObject Tree/SOBject Collections API (the one with 200 subrequests).

Does it work like batch (each sub is 1 API call) or as composite (all subs together are 1 API call)?

Answer (score 2):

I can't find this in the documentation, but I tested it in Workbench, and it is just 1 API call per transaction, for up to 200 records.